# c# directly getting the base attribute

Tags: c#, get, attributes, radix

is there an easy way to get the attribute of the base class that another class inherit? Currently below is what i am doing.

```
class baseClass
{
    public int A = 0;
    public string B = "Hello";
}
class ChildA : baseClass 
{

}
class ChildB : baseClass 
{

}

class CRunContainer 
{
    ChildA childA = new ChildA();
    ChildB childB = new ChildB();

    void getAttribute(object objChild) 
    {
        int iA = 0;
        string strB = "";
        if (objChild is ChildA)
        {
            iA = ((ChildA)objChild).A;
            strB = ((ChildA)objChild).B;
        }
        if (objChild is ChildB)
        {
            iA = ((ChildB)objChild).A;
            strB = ((ChildB)objChild).B;
        }
    }
}
```

In the method getAttribute, Is there a way to directly get the base attribute without the need to check the type and cast the object?
Something like objChild.A.
Or by passing the base class of the inherit class as an argument in the method
Something like

```
void getAttribute(baseClass baseClass) 
    {
        int iA = baseClass.A;
        string strB = baseClass.B;           
    }

    void run() 
    {
        getAttribute(base.childA);
    }
```

Comment: Change `object` to `baseClass`

Comment: Hi Bob How would i pass in the base then? in run() method, how should i pass in?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's wrong with just writing the code as you've shown after the "Something like"? It should work _exactly_ just like that. Are you having some problem getting that to work? It's not clear what `base.childA` is supposed to be, but maybe you need to just write `getAttribute(childA)` (assuming `childA` is just a variable referring to an instance of `ChildA`)

Comment: Hi Peter The problem arise when you have a lot of class inheriting baseClass the get getAttribute will eventually become very big with lots of check on the objectType and casting of that object to access to the base attribute. If there are a 100 class inheriting the base, there will be 100 checks and 100 casting. Not to mention the number of attribute that needs to be assigned

Answer (score 1):

just do

```
 void getAttribute(baseClass child) 
 {
    int iA = child.A;
    string strB = child.B;
 }
```

then you can do

```
  getAttribute(childA)
  getAttribute(childB)
```

Comment: Cool Thanks didint know i can pass in the derived instance directly into the method argument.

Comment: it's the whole point :) anywhere the base is you should be able to pass any child in.    Also defined as a principle of OO with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle